# VBA code to select sells on the basis of values in them

Tags: vba

I am trying to write a small piece of code that selects all cells containing "D" in the range A1:J10. Sorry if the code below is sub-optimal for the purpose, but I am trying to use this as a means of learning the language. There seems to be no obvious error in the code (to me), but it says 'Invalid procedure call or argument' when I try to run it.

```
Option Explicit


Dim t As Range
Dim finalrange As Range

Sub selectallbattleships()
    For Each t In Range("A1:J10")
        If t.Value = "D" Then Set finalrange = Application.Union(finalrange, t)
    Next t

finalrange.Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give `finalrange` an initial Range, otherwise it starts off as `Nothing`. The code is failing at `Application.Union(finalrange, t)` because it's trying to Union `Nothing`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues here.

First your Dim statements should be inside the sub. Next, you cannot union `nothing`, so you need to check if finalrange has been assigned to anything yet, then decide how to treat it - in this case if it hasn't then just assign it to `t`, otherwise `union`. Lastly, you do not need 'Application.' before `union`.

```
Sub selectallbattleships()
    Dim t As Range
    Dim finalrange As Range

    For Each t In Range("A1:J10")
        If t.Value = "D" Then
            If finalrange Is Nothing Then
                Set finalrange = t
            Else
                Set finalrange = Union(finalrange, t)
            End If
        End If
    Next t

finalrange.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: FYI, the dimensioned variables don't need to be inside the subroutine. What if they wanted them set as global variables that could be accessed by other subroutines.